# How can I input an expression like x^2+2x to SymPy

Tags: python, replace, sympy

How can one convert a string (that a user might enter) like `x^2+2x` into `x**2+2*x` so it can be solved by SymPy?

Comment: Try finding the desired peace of the string (probably with a regex), then replace it with the new one. Because you know what you have found (again, because you have a right regex), you can be certain that the replacement works well

Comment: But how do i make it that it should find a-z or 1-9 or should i write long if elif statement?

Comment: use bracket `[]`. e.g. `[\d\w]+ `.  how about test it out here: https://regexr.com/

Comment: `from sympy.parsing.mathematica import mathematica` then `mathematica('x^2+2x')` -> `x**2 + 2*x`. I can say more if this is reopened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SymPy has the ability to parse expressions from strings. See the `parsing` directory and documentation for more options. But for the case you gave, the existing `mathematica` parser will work:

```
>>> from sympy.parsing.mathematica import mathematica
>>> mathematica('x^2+2x')
x**2 + 2*x
```

If you are accepting input from users you will have to provide a guide for forms of expressions that are acceptable and watch for parsing errors from the calls to the parser (`mathematica` or `parse_expr`, for example). If the user can enter a SymPy compatible string then `sympify` will be enough to convert it to a SymPy expression.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your immediate response